# C# data structure: What type of collection should I use?

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections

For each item in the collection, I need to have a short string and a few int16 fields. I want to iterate through the collection using the string field (meaning I don't want to use numeric index to iterate).
The collection is at most about 10 items. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Great link: [C#/.NET Fundamentals: Choosing the Right Collection Class](http://blackrabbitcoder.net/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` should work for you needs.

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
dictionary.Add("key", new List<int>{1,2,3,4});
...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use .NET 4 and the "few int16" are always the same number of values you might also want to consider the `Tuple` class as value in the dictionary:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<Int16, Int16, Int16>>();
map["Foo"] = Tuple.Create(1, 2, 3);

var values = map["Foo"];
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", value.Item1, value.Item2, value.Item3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `Dictionary` so you can index into it using an arbitrary key - `string`, in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean **iterate** as looping thru; then it really does not matter because all collections support `foreach`:

```
 foreach (var item in collection) { ... }
```

However, if you mean **iterate** as indexing, then a `Dictionary` should do the job.

```
 class SomeFields { public int a; public int b; ... }

 var collection = new Dictionary<string, SomeFields>();
 collection.Add("name", new SomeFields() { a = 1, b = 2 });

 var fields = collection["name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the items in the collection is small "10 items or less" then better for performance to use [ListDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.listdictionary.aspx), If you are not sure about the elements count or if the element count maybe increase in the future then use [HaybridDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.hybriddictionary.aspx).

Note that HybridDictionary mechanism is to use internally a ListDictionary while the collection is small, and then switching to a Hashtable when the collection gets large.

Comment: Both of your recommendations are non-generic and should be considered pretty much obsolete these days unless you have a *really* good reason to use them over the generic collections added since .NET2 came along.

Comment: I don't use them either, but this is homework you know, and at the C# 2.0 fundamentals exam "70-636" this is still the answer...